# DirectX copy array data into constant buffer

Tags: directx-11

If the we want to update a struct of constant buffer contains a vector,
just use copyMemory or memcpy with struct starting pointer and the size of the struct, will not copy vector data, is it right?

```
struct PerObjectCB {
XMFLOAT4X4 World;
XMFLOAT4X4 WorldInvTranspose;
XMFLOAT4X4 TexTransform;
Material Mat;
vector<XMFLOAT4X4> BoneTransforms;
};
PerObjectCB Data = {.,.,., ..., {/*BoneTransforms data*/}};
ID3D11Buffer* mBuffer;
ID3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc = {...};
device->CreateBuffer(&desc, 0, &mBuffer);
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
dc->Map(mBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
CopyMemory(mappedResource.pData, &Data, sizeof(Data));
dc->Unmap(mBuffer, 0);
```

I put these update constant buffer codes into a template class, then I can use this class to manage update constant buffer, however when I encounter the animation data vector, I test with cout << sizeof(vector < XMFLOAT4X4 > BoneTransforms), no matter how many data I put in the vector, the size of this vector is always 12, I guess the struct only store the vector's starting address, the really data is at somewhere else. If this is true, how can I deal with this?

Do I really have to give up the template class I wrote for constant buffer management and write another function for update array type data specifically?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that `std::vector` is not POD (plain old data).

```
struct PerObjectCB {
XMFLOAT4X4 World;
XMFLOAT4X4 WorldInvTranspose;
XMFLOAT4X4 TexTransform;
Material Mat;
vector<XMFLOAT4X4> BoneTransforms;
};
```

This is going to be `sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4) * 3 + sizeof(Material) + sizeof(std::vector)`. It has nothing at all to do with `BoneTransforms.size() * sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4)`.

If you are going to send bone transforms in this CB, you need to pick a 'maximum bone size'

```
struct PerObjectCB {
XMFLOAT4X4 World;
XMFLOAT4X4 WorldInvTranspose;
XMFLOAT4X4 TexTransform;
Material Mat;
XMFLOAT4X4 BoneTransforms[MAX_BONES];
};
```

> Note that you are unlikely to need non-affine transformations for bones, so you should use XMFLOAT4X3 instead to save memory and more importantly transfer bandwidth

For example, in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) the `SkinnedEffect` shader has a maximum number of bones of 72. The CB it uses look like:

```
struct SkinnedEffectConstants
{
    XMVECTOR diffuseColor;
    XMVECTOR emissiveColor;
    XMVECTOR specularColorAndPower;

    XMVECTOR lightDirection[IEffectLights::MaxDirectionalLights];
    XMVECTOR lightDiffuseColor[IEffectLights::MaxDirectionalLights];
    XMVECTOR lightSpecularColor[IEffectLights::MaxDirectionalLights];

    XMVECTOR eyePosition;

    XMVECTOR fogColor;
    XMVECTOR fogVector;

    XMMATRIX world;
    XMVECTOR worldInverseTranspose[3];
    XMMATRIX worldViewProj;

    XMVECTOR bones[SkinnedEffect::MaxBones][3];
};
```

The `DGSLEffect` skinning shader uses five distinct CBs, with one of them containing the bones:

```
// Slot 4
struct BoneConstants
{
    XMVECTOR Bones[DGSLEffect::MaxBones][3];
};
```

> The original VS Starter Kit DGSL skinned shader supported 59 bones.

**You may ask, why 72?**

This comes from the fact that the built-in shaders in DirectX Tool Kit borrowed from XNA Game Studio 4 support Direct3D Feature Level 9.1 hardware. Internally these shaders use the `vs_2_0` profile which requires 256 vector constants. 72 bones takes up 216 of them, and the rest of the constants pushes it up to 242 which leaves a dozen or so for the 10level9 implementation.

If you require Feature Level 10.0 or later hardware, you could make it larger without much performance impact. Keep in mind that the total size of a CB impacts how expensive it is to update.